# The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

Brand new Xamarin Cross-Platform project.
Solution comprises of:

1. A Xamarin (Xamarin Forms) android project
2. Shared (.NET Standard 2.0) Class Library
   project, where 'App' is defined.

Both projects build with no errors or warnings.
However, when trying to run them I get the following error:

> error: The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Failed to debug
>   your app.

It looks like a caching thing related to visual studio but I tried cleaning all caches (.vs, obj, release, restart VS, etc..)

Context:
I'm Using Visual Studio 2017.
Tried running the app on an emulator and on a real phone (Xamarin Live)
The app did run for a while but after an hour or so this error started popping out. 
Tried plenty (I would love to say all but maybe missed one) solutions I found over SE and Xamarin forums. None helped.

[image: Reference to 'App']

Comment: "App" is typically the default name of the class in your shared/PCL project that contains the app logic.  You either are missing a reference/using statement, or the template named that class incorrectly.

Comment: As I mentioned, the android project references the shared project and they both build successfully (meaning during Build time VS does find the definition of App). If you click 'Go To definition' on 'App' it does find the definition of 'App'.

Comment: sorry, I evidently didn't read your question carefully enough :-)

Comment: happens very often. delete obj/bin folders and rebuild solution.

Comment: I tried that but it only sporadically helps. 
Honestly I'm happy to try other voodoo procedures you may have in mind...

Comment: for me it happens also very often and this is the only workaround that helps a bit.

Comment: After a lot of trials and errors I realized it's not deterministic and just depends on the availability of the nuget packages, MSBuild products and the synching between them. That's the reason why sometimes packages regresh, VS restart, machine restart help. for example, sometimes a resource or library file are locked when needed by one of the processes in the loop debugger/ builder/ RT engine and is not available or not copied when expected....

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this error occurs when I create a new project where the name and solution have a space. Try creating one without a space.

For example: "MyAwesomeApp" instead of "My Awesome App"